# Adding a NSTimer to a button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, nstimer

I have searched all over the web with no luck of making this project work with a timer, I end up with a crashed app every time when using the timer.

For testing and learning purposes I build little simple apps. It is a button that sends a rocket from the bottom of the screen and disappears off screen, along with a rocket sound effect.

I am wanting to add a Timer to the button so that when the button is held down the rocket will launch, reset, and launch over and over until I release the button. I think my only hope now is to paste code from my .h & .m files and hopefully someone can tell me what I need to do and where the proper code needs to be added for this project.

Thank you so much for the help, it is greatly appreciated.

.H FILE:

```
//  MVViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface MVViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *moveMe2;

//New action to repeat launch (Touch Down)
- (IBAction)rocketRepeat:(id)sender;

//New action to stop launch (Touch Up Inside)
- (IBAction)rocketStop:(id)sender;

//This is the original launch button (Touch Down)
- (IBAction)yourRocketButton:(id)sender; 

@end
```

---

.M FILE

```
//  MVViewController.m

#import "MVViewController.h"

@interface MVViewController ()

@end

@implementation MVViewController {
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
}

@synthesize moveMe2;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setMoveMe2:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown));
}

- (IBAction)rocketRepeat:(id)sender
//Getting error "Use of undeclared identifier 'yourRocketButton'
{
    [yourRocketButton addTarget:self action:@selector(rocketRepeat:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
}

- (IBAction)rocketStop:(id)sender 
//Getting error "Use of undeclared identifier 'yourRocketButton'
{
    [yourRocketButton addTarget:self action:@selector(rocketStop:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (IBAction)yourRocketButton:(id)sender {
    moveMe2.center = CGPointMake(100.0f, 408.0f);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{moveMe2.center = CGPointMake(100, -55);}]; 
}

@end
```

@@@@@@@@

**EDIT** **This is what finally worked**

```
//  RKViewController.m

#import "RKViewController.h"

@interface RKViewController ()

@end

@implementation RKViewController
@synthesize RocketMove;
@synthesize Launch;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setRocketMove:nil];
    [self setLaunch:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown));
}

- (IBAction)rocketRepeat:(id)sender {
    [self performSelector:@selector(rocketRepeat:) withObject:self afterDelay:1.0];
    RocketMove.center = CGPointMake(100.0f, 408.0f);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{RocketMove.center = CGPointMake(100, -55);}];
}

- (IBAction)rocketStop:(id)sender {
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
}
@end
```

---

```
//  RKViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RKViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *RocketMove;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *Launch;

- (IBAction)rocketRepeat:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)rocketStop:(id)sender;
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `UIControlEvent` for this purpose.

**1.** You need two separate `IBAction`s for each purpose, say one for holding down the button, one after the button is released.

**2.** For holding down the button you need to use `UIControlEventTouchDown`. So have a `rocketRepeat` action where you keep calling the rocket action using the `NSTimer` with regular intervals and use:

```
 [yourRocketButton addTarget:self action:@selector(rocketRepeat:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

**3.** Then use another action with `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` where you will invalidate the `NSTimer` so the rocket stops. Call that action `rocketStop` or something and use:

```
[yourRocketButton addTarget:self action:@selector(rocketStop:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

**---EDIT---**

Action 1 :

```
- (IBAction)rocketRepeat:(id)sender
{
    //code for starting rocker, timer action
}
```

Action 2:

```
- (IBAction)rocketStop:(id)sender
{
   //Code for stopping rocket
}
```

`yourButton` is not an action, its a UIButton. I hope you have created a button in the IB, drag and dropped the button.  And in `viewDidLoad` you write these 2 lines of code :

Instead of `yourButton` you write the name of the button you have dragged dropped from the IB. I hope you know how to add a button from the interface builder and connect it.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [yourRocketButton addTarget:self action:@selector(rocketRepeat:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown]; //For touch down button action
  [yourRocketButton addTarget:self action:@selector(rocketStop:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; //When button is let go.

    [super viewDidLoad];


   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Comment: I re wrote the code with the action names you provided and made the proper connections. I am getting a error on each IBAction in the .M file. I renamed my animation action "yourRocketButton". The errors say "use of undeclared identifier 'yourRocketButton' (I'm sure I just misunderstood you or something)

Comment: @sdlabs `yourRocketButton` is just an example name, you should replace it with name of your button, the button that you use to tap on.

Comment: I reconnected the IBAction for the animation to match your example. Am I missing something when it comes to actually giving a button a name?

Comment: @sdlabs, In the example i gave, i assumed you wanted to move the rocket depending on the tap of the button, so i assumed you had a button connected from IB, so what i have basically given is a method in which when you tap on a button(yourButton) the rocket moves, when you let go of the button rocket stops. Have i got the question wrong?

Comment: I edited my original post to reflect the changes I made to the code. I am sorry I keep misunderstanding you. Maybe it's just my frustration with these timers over the past few days. Most of the other programming aspects I have picked up fairly quick.

Comment: @sdlabs, sorry was away for lunch, looked at your code, that's not what i meant you to do. I'll edit my answer a little, just check.

Comment: @sdlabs, i hope you know how to create a button from IB, or programmatically ?

Comment: Maybe there was a miscommunication. I wanted to be able to touch the button and as long as I keep holding down the button the rocket would keep repeating the animation over and over until I release the button, then it would stop. The way it is now, I press the button or press and hold and the rocket animates once, until the button is pressed again. I just need it to repeat until I let go of the button. Kind of like a machine gun, I want full auto, not single shot.

Comment: @sdlabs, yes that's what i had in mind, there should be some button action you are giving right ? Some `IBAction` that you hook up from the IB to the button. You would have hooked it up as `TouchUpInside`, i want you to use `TouchUpInside` for rocketStop action, and `TouchDown` for rocket start action.

Comment: I added a edit above to show the code that finally worked out for me. I'm not sure if it is the proper way to do it but it works. Thanks for everything, I'm sure you were getting frustrated dealing with me.

Comment: @sdlabs, No frustration whatsoever :D, even i'm a learner and i've gone through lots of frustration, now you'll be much clear about my `yourButton` solution i guess, now you have to replace `yourButton` with `Launch` and i hope you get what you needed. Your solution works well too :D, Good luck in future. Happy iCoding!

Answer (score 1):

If you want that the rockets are autolaunched once you press the button, you should add the following code to your rocketLaunch: method. If you want them to start appearing from the beginning, call this from your viewDidLoad method.

```
- (void)launchRocketsTimer
{
    [self.timer invalidate]; //you have to create a NSTimer property to your view controller
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.5 target:self selector:@selector(scheduledRocketLaunch:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)scheduledRocketLaunch:(NSTimer *)t
{
    moveme2.center = _bottom_point_; //set it where you would like it to start
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{moveMe2.center = CGPointMake(100, -55);}];
}
```

Remember to release your timer in dealloc.

Oh, and one more thing:
You have a memory leak on your rocketsound: method when you allocate your AVAudioPlayer. You may replace the code with this one:

```
- (IBAction)rocketsound:(id)sender
 {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/rocketlaunch.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

    NSError *error;
    if (self.audioPlayer == nil)
    {
        self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error] autorelease]; //Note the use of setter property and the autorelease. (you could use your own code because the if will prevent the leak in this case).
    }

    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;

    if (audioPlayer == nil)
        NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);
    else 
        [audioPlayer play];
}
```